# Can't Get Power BI to Connect to R: ADO.NET error

Tags: r, powerbi, ado.net

I am trying to load data into Power BI using this script:

```
Constituents<-read.csv("C:/Users/[etc]/Constituents.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Despite all my attempts to get Power BI to talk to R, I keep getting this error message:

> Details: "ADO.NET: R script error. Warning message: In
> utils::memory.limit(size = 4000) : cannot decrease memory limit:
> ignored Error: object 'data.R' not found Execution halted

I've tried different versions of R and adding the index to the top of the script.

Anyone here able to get Power BI to talk to R?

Comment: The first part was a warning that was ignored the second part seem to be the problem `Error: object 'data.R' not found Execution halted`. May need to use an absolute path.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The error says that `object 'data.R' ` could not be found. You say nothing about such an object, so I assume there's more to the story than you are disclosing. Perhaps the setup of your PowerBI installation is not finding that object because it is looking is some sort of relative path and the setup  might need to be changed so that it goes to wherever that resource is located.